# jQuery offset() incorrect in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.9.1's `offset()` function to try and get the position of something when it is clicked. I have found though that the values returned are incorrect when using chrome on android or using chrome dev tools to simulate a nexus device.

As long as the page isn't zoomed then it works as expected but if the page is zoomed the values returned by offset() are out by the amount the window is scrolled horizontally and vertically.

I can get round this by adding on the `$(window).scrollTop()` and `$(window).scrollLeft()` values to the values returned by `offset()` but this then means its out on all other devices.

The issue only seems to exist on Android, I have tested in Chrome on an iPad and `offset()` works as expected regardless of whether I zoom or not.

Is there a way to overcome this other than trying to check the user agent for Android Chrome which I would imagine could be unreliable.

Comment: Welcome to mobile development!